# How to use res.redirect after successful download of file with res.download in Express JS?

Tags: node.js, express

What I'm trying to do is download a file and after downloading, delete the given file, redirect to another page and display a flash message (see code below):

```
fs.writeFileSync(user.username + "_invoice_data.xml", tofile);

res.download(user.username + "_invoice_data.xml", function(err){
    if(err){
        fs.unlinkSync(user.username + "_invoice_data.xml");
        req.flash("error", "Valid. Download error...");
        return res.redirect('/arinvoicedata');
    }
    else{
        fs.unlinkSync(user.username + "_invoice_data.xml");
        req.flash("success", "Valid. Downloading...");
        return res.redirect('/arinvoicedata');
    }
});
```

However, I get the following error message:

> Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent
>   to the client

The file itself gets downloaded, however the error above crashes the server all the time. Does this mean, that res.redirect inside the callback of res.download is not permitted? What solutions would you suggest? Thanks!

Comment: That's actually not possible ,you have to handle that at client side .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You are not permitted to send header after sending response of a request.
2. You need client side javascript for download progress tracking

Comment: Thanks. Not exactly what I wanted to hear, but rules are rules:)

Comment: You're most welcome. There are tools available which will make your life easy. Just let me give you the general idea.

Comment: Use a http request tool in frontend like fetch or axios on frontend. While it is getting file, get the information of how much bytes are received and how much is remaining. If remaining bytes is 0, you redirect webpage using window.location.href

Answer (score 0):

```
const express = require('express');

const path = require('path');

const port = 3000;

var app =express();

app.get("/success", (req, res)=>{

res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "/success.html");

});

app.get("/download", (req, res)=>{

res.download(path.join(__dirname, "/img", "/download.jpg");

res.redirect("/success");

});

app.listen(process.env.PORT || port, (err)=>{

if(err) throw err;

console.log(`app listening on port ${port}`);

});
```

Comment: you might want to try this

Comment: You should always add some explanation to your answer to improve its quality and make it more clear. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer