# Failed to create route that download a file and send message response: "Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client"

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, routes

I am trying to create a route so that when someone accesses it, it will download a file and send a response message to the user (should appear in the HTML). I am using the [`download`](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.download) function from express JS but it failed.

This is my code:

```
router.get('/api/zip', AuthMiddleware, (req, res) => {
    //console.log("hello");

    //return res.status(200).download(".\\views\\index.zip"); => download but doesn't send message to the user.  
    
    res.download(".\\views\\index.zip", "index.zip", (err) => {
        if (err) {
          res.status(500).send({
            message: "Could not download the file. " + err,
          });
        } else {
            try {
                res.status(200).send("Download!");
            } catch (error) {
                res.status(500).send("Download fail 2");
            }
            
        }
      });
});
```

After the user access `http://localhost:4000/api/zip`, it downloads the file and the server crashes:

```
[nodemon] starting `node index.js`
Listening on port 4000
_http_outgoing.js:561
    throw new ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT('set');
    ^

Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
    at new NodeError (internal/errors.js:322:7)
    at ServerResponse.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:561:11)
    at ServerResponse.header (D:\MyProject\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:794:10)
    at ServerResponse.send (D:\MyProject\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:174:12)
    at D:\MyProject\routes\index.js:34:21
    at D:\MyProject\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:450:22
    at SendStream.onend (D:\MyProject\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:1078:5)
    at SendStream.emit (events.js:400:28)
    at ReadStream.onend (D:\MyProject\node_modules\send\index.js:813:10)
    at ReadStream.emit (events.js:412:35) {
  code: 'ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT'
```

I understand that I can't use `download` and then `send`, so how can I download and send message to the user on the HTML page?

Comment: How about handling the error in your front-end, if it succeeds show the HTML message for success, else show the HTML message for error. I'm sure res.download sends some kind of error status.

Comment: This is a good idea but if someone copy pastes the URL `http://localhost:4000/api/zip` to the browser, how can I send it to the front end? the frond end is in the path `/api/zip`.

Comment: Hmmm interesting, there should be a way to communicate cross-page in your stack.

Answer (score 1):

You already know that you can't send 2 responses one after the other.

What can be done, is setting a custom header for your response, so something like this:

```
app.get('/download', (req, res) => {

   res.append('message', JSON.stringify({ message : "hello"}) ); 
   res.download("test.txt", "try.txt");

});
```

And then get the message from that, It feels really "hacky" though...

Comment: thanks, it adds it in the response header but doesn't redirect the user to the HTML with the message "hello"

Comment: If you want to redirect then I suggest to take a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61387874/12603198)